# casperjs: how to include other javascript files during unit tests in tests themselves?

Tags: dependency-injection, casperjs

I am doing some unit test in casperjs and I got stuck: how do include dependency file from the test itself? Included javascript file can be just a bunch of functions, and does not declare any interface (module.exports = ...  etc).

I know I can include from the command line

`$ casperjs test --include=./my-mock.js mytest.js`

but how can I include files from the test itself?

Putting following on the top does not work for me... my_mock is undefined
`casper.options.clientScripts = ["./my-mock.js"]; //push() does not help either`

```
//mytest.js is below
// ------------------------------------------
casper.test.begin('ajax mock test', function suite(test) {

  my_mock.setFetchedData("bla");

  my_mock.doRequest();

  test.assertEquals( ......);

  test.done();
});

// ------------------------------------------
```

CasperJS version 1.1.0-DEV   using phantomjs version 1.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found useful this [sample](https://gist.github.com/n1k0/3813361) demonstrating `--includes` option:

```
$ casperjs test tests/ --pre=pre.js --includes=inc.js --post=post.js
```

to load functions that you often use in your tests.

Answer (score 5):

Using phantom.injectJs method is the best option I've found so far. E.g. you're having two files in your directory: "tests.js" and "settings.js". You want to include "settings.js" into "test.js". The first thing you should do with your "test.js" is write the following:

```
phantom.injectJs('settings.js'); 

casper.test.begin(...
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that `clientScripts` isn't working is that it is loaded on each page load, so you don't have access to the objects/functions defined in the file outside of a `casper.evaluate()` call.

You can use `require()` to pull in modules, however you may need to modify your included script to work with this method.

Here is what I changed your `mytest.js` to:

```js
var my_mock = require('my-mock');

casper.test.begin('ajax mock test', function suite(test) {
  my_mock.setFetchedData("bla");
  my_mock.doRequest();
  //test.assertEquals( ... );
  test.done();
});
```

And this is a quick script (`my-mock.js`) that I threw together to print out when you use the functions you provided.

```js
module.exports = {
  setFetchedData: function(a) {
    console.log('setFetchedData: ' + a);
  },
  doRequest: function() {
    console.log('doRequest');
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks, that's solution if you want to include the javascript file that conforms to some specific format (module.exports = ... ). In my case I need to include any javascript file which can be just a bunch of functions... Is there a way for that? I have update my question.